# Jquery click event on smartphone and Desktop browsers issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using following code

```
$("p").click(function(){
  alert("You clicked on paragraph");
});
```

It works well on all desktop browsers but not in any mobile browsers ? How can I write a code which work both in Desktop and mobile/tablet ?

Answer (score 0):

Bind **click** and **touchstart** event. On desktop browsers will be intercepted the click event , on mobile browser the touchstart event

```
var flagEvent = false;
$("p").bind('touchstart click', function(){
     if (!flagEvent) {
        flagEvent = true;
        setTimeout(function(){ flagEvent = false; }, 100);

        //your code

      }

      return false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this also works

```
var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");

$("a").bind(clickHandler, function(e) {
    alert("clicked or tapped. This button used: " + clickHandler);
});
```

Can I use ajax calls also inside the above function ?

Comment: As of jQuery version 1.7, the on() method is the new replacement for the bind()

Comment: is this an answer or a question or both?

Comment: I think this will solve my issue but I need to check ajax calls.I haven't tried ajax calls in mobiles yet.SO I posted answer+ question.Sorry If it creates any issues

Comment: ِAjax works on handheld devices, not all of them,  e.g. old BB doesn't support Ajax. If you have another question even a related one to this, it's better to post a new question.

Comment: Do I need to attach jquery mobile js  in order to work in mobile or just jquery.js

Comment: You can do it in pure JavaScript. Google touch events handling JavaScript.